# Sending json Array with Python

Tags: python, json, asp.net-web-api, python-requests, urllib2

I have an MVC Web Api and I can add new record with below request with "simple REST Client"

```
URL: http://localhost:4585/api/users
Headers: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Data:
[{
"username": "name1",
"email": "mail1",
"password": "password1"
},
{
"username": "name2",
"email": "mail2",
"password": "password2"
}]
```

What I want is doing same thing with python. I've tried below code but the API processed only first record properly.

```
import json
import urllib2
data = [{ "username": "name1", "email": "mail1", "password": "password1" }, { "username": "name2", "email": "mail2", "password": "password2" }]
response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: Are there any server-side logs with more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it with requests library.

```
import requests

requests_session = requests.session()
requests_session.headers.update({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
requests_session.headers.update({'charset':'utf-8'})

post_data = '[{ "username": "name1", "email": "mail1", "password": "password1" }, { "username": "name2", "email": "mail2", "password": "password2" }]'

requests_response = requests_session.post(url="http://localhost:4585/api/users", data=post_data)

print requests_response.content
```

Comment: This is a good and clear solution. The trick for me was to use `{ 'Authorization': ..., 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'charset':'utf-8' }` object directly as headers.